Excel VBA, Selenium 2.0.9.0: I am tring to download a website graph an Image. Consumer Confidence
I am trying to download a website graph as an image to my desktop. Then, ultimately, place the image inside an Excel Worksheet.  It's not grabbing the image with a variety of CSS Selectors that I have tried:
Sub ConsumerConfidenceChart()

''save Path = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\downloaded_image.png"
' Set imgElement = driver.FindElementByCss("#chConferences > p:nth-child(13) > img") ' Adjust selector as needed
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim imageURL As String
    Dim picture As picture
    
    ' Set up Selenium WebDriver
    Dim driver As New WebDriver
    Dim imgElement As WebElement
    Dim savePath As String, fullSavePath As String
    Dim pic As picture
    Dim LeftPos As Long, TopPos As Long, width As Long, height As Long

    ' Initialize WebDriver and open the target webpage
    driver.Start "Chrome"
    driver.Get "https://www.conference-board.org/topics/consumer-confidence" ' Replace with actual URL
    
    ' Set the worksheet where you want to insert the image
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Consumer") ' Change "Sheet1" to your sheet name
    
    ' Image URL from the webpage (example: replace with actual URL found in HTML inspection)
    Set MyImage = driver.FindElementByCss("#chConferences > p:nth-child(13) > img")
    
    ' Insert the picture into the worksheet
    Set picture = ws.Pictures.Insert(MyImage)
    
    ' Position and size the picture as needed
    With MyImage
        .Top = ws.Range("A1").Top ' Set the top position
        .Left = ws.Range("A1").Left ' Set the left position
        .width = 400 ' Set the width
        .height = 300 ' Set the height
    End With
End Sub

